# Flappy Bird Coding Error in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I've encountered a coding error for my flappy bird project, in Xcode 6.1.

The code is to allow rotation of the bird, and it reads:

```
bird.zRotation = self.acotarMinMax(-1, max: 0.3, valor: bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy * (bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001))
```

the error occurs under `dy`, it reads:

```
value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

How can I correct the error, or is there another way to generate rotation?

I am a total beginner of Swift, so I'm having a hard time figuring out if this is a syntax problem or something to do with the updated version.

I obtained the code from a online tutorial, and it worked in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on the Swift `Optional` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

So it seems that `dy` is an Optional value, which means that it either has a value or it does not, but you don't know until you look into it (like Schroedinger's Cat). So if you need this value and you know it will not be `nil`, you unwrap it by writing `bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy!` which will look into the "box" and take the value out but crash if there is nothing inside. If you write `dy?` it will look into the box but ignore it if the box is empty.

More on Optional Chaining (which is what you do) here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: Feel free to vote up or mark as the correct answer, if this helped you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured out my error.

As Sebastian correctly pointed out, it is to do with optional chaining.

The code that worked is:

```
bird.zRotation = self.acotarMinMax(-1, max: 1, valor: bird.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * (bird.physicsBody!.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.002 : 0.002))
```

I used '!' to force a value on physicsBody. The precise mechanism of why this works is still a blur to me. But my guess is to do with the new version's correction method.